# How to open a specific activity using OneSignal?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using onesignal to send push notifications.
I used this sample code to open a specific activity when user clicks on push notification.
If I want to open another specific activity, What should I do?

```
 package com.moho.app;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
    import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
    import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

    import org.json.JSONObject;


    public class MyNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String activityToBeOpened;
            String activity;

            //While sending a Push notification from OneSignal dashboard
            // you can send an addtional data named "activityToBeOpened" and retrieve the value of it and do necessary operation
            //If key is "activityToBeOpened" and value is "AnotherActivity", then when a user clicks
            //on the notification, AnotherActivity will be opened.
            //Else, if we have not set any additional data MainActivity is opened.
            if (data != null) {
                activityToBeOpened = data.optString("activityToBeOpened", null);
                if (activityToBeOpened != null && activityToBeOpened.equals("AnotherActivity")) {
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + activityToBeOpened);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.getContext(), AboutUs.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    MainMenu.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                } else if (activityToBeOpened != null && activityToBeOpened.equals("MainActivity")) {
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + activityToBeOpened);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.getContext(), MainMenu.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    MainMenu.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.getContext(), MainMenu.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    MainMenu.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would the code of your ApplicationClass.java:

```
package com.application;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenedHandler())
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
    }

    public class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler
    {
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result)
        {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String activityToBeOpened;
            String activity;

            if (data != null)
            {
                activityToBeOpened = data.optString("activityToBeOpened", null);
                if (activityToBeOpened != null && activityToBeOpened.equals("ABC"))
                {
                    Log.i("OneSignal", "customkey set with value: " + activityToBeOpened);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationClass.this, ABCActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (activityToBeOpened != null && activityToBeOpened.equals("DEF"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationClass.this, DEFActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Customise the code to suit your needs (change the value of the data and the name of the class).

I tried to set an empty Additional Data to open MainActivity, but, that didn't work in my case. It's probably because I have defined:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE"/>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml. So, I guess, you'll have to set another additional data value to open MainActivity too if you need. Just add another `else if` after the ones already included to go on adding more keys and activities to launch.

If you're going to use all these intents, make sure to have not have anything setup for `android:launchMode` in your AndroidManifest.xml for the activities that you're going to launch using the notifications. Basically, it shouldn't exist.

Also, to make this thing work, you'll have to change your AndroidManifest.xml to something like this:

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
```

The only mandatory part in this code for the purpose of the notifications to work is the `android:name=".ApplicationClass"`.

Hope this helps.